# Implicit css style of parent when grandparent parent child pattern is known

Tags: css

I have this situation in html and css:

css

```
.heading-border{ border-bottom:2px groove; }
```

html (edited for brevity)

```
 <tr class="heading-border">
  <th>Some Label</th>
```

Is there some way to target the `<tr>` here from css, **not javascript**, without having to explicitly define the class (in other words assign this style to any `<tr>` which contains a `<th>`? The reason is that this situation exists in many places and I would prefer not to have to mark a class in every place.

Comment: Are you using a thead in your table markup?

Comment: @kinakuta - Nope, although that is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible, but we may have it in Level 4 Selectors. In the future you will be able to explicitly declare the subject of the selector by prefixing it with the dollar sign:

```
$div p {
  /* div is the subject, not p */
}
```

One note on the symbol above is that it appears to up in the air still. I've read reports that it will be `?`, and others which suggest that it will be `!`. Bottom line, watch the spec :)

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, no. Not with just CSS. Its not smart enough to work backwards like that from a child. You can only nest one way.